# Accept different variants of an inputted string in Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
prompt = "\nTell me something, and i will repeat it back to you: "
prompt +="\nEnter 'quit' to end the program. "

message = ""
while message != 'quit'.lower():
     message = input(prompt)
     print(message)
```

I tried to have someone input something and to also have them enter 'quit' to exit out of the program, however, I want the 'quit' entered to cover all instances of the word. So upper case, lower case etc. I thought using the .lower() would work if I entered 'QUIT' but it didn't. How I could get it so anyway that 'quit' is entered would exit the program? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmYTM.png)

Comment: You're lowercasing the static string, not the user input. Just use `while message.lower() != 'quit'`. I'm voting to close this question since it's basically a typo. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking whether the input message is equal to 'quit' in lowercase (because it already is), you should check if the input message in lowercase is equal to 'quit'.

```
prompt = "\nTell me something, and i will repeat it back to you: "
prompt +="\nEnter 'quit' to end the program. "

message = ""
while message.lower() != 'quit':
     message = input(prompt)
     print(message)
```